# Which gcc switch disables "left-hand operand of comma has no effect" warning?

Tags: gcc, warnings

It's a part of larger code base, which forces -Werror on gcc. This warning is generated in a third party code that shouldn't be changed (and I actually know how to fix it), but I can disable specific warnings. This time man gcc failed me, so please, let some gcc master enlighten me. TIA.

Comment: Many GNU programs have abbreviated man pages. The "info" pages and HTML documentation are usually much more thorough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the *-Wno-unused-value* option, see the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)

Comment: That made it, thank you! To be literal it's Wno-unused-value though.

Answer (score 5):

If you use -fdiagnostics-show-option, GCC will tell you how to disable a warning (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [diagnostic pragma](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) directive?  These are available in gcc 4.2.1+, I believe.

Comment: That would have the same effect, but I can't edit the files. Thanks anyway, I may need that later.